# mongodb select parent subdocument based on child subdocument's array

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to get a list of all Mary Mack's shifts from the volunteers collection but I keep getting back either nothing or everything.  Can someone please help me?  I've tried several ways, some are listed below.

I'd like the data to look like:

```
where          date         time          details
__________________________________________________________
Registration   2017-06-24   8AM - NOON    check people in
```

I've got volunteers data that looks like this:

```
{
  where: "Registration",
  description: "blah blah blah",
  shifts: [{
    dateNeeded: "2017-06-24",
    timeslot: "8AM - NOON",
    details: "check people in",
    volunteers: [{
      name: "Mary Mack",
      phone: 1234567890,
      email: "mary@mack.com"
    }]
  }] 
}
```

I've tried:

```
Volunteer.find({"shifts.volleyteers.email": "mary@mack.com" }, {         "shifts.$": 1, "where": 1 })
```

I've also tried aggregation and filtering:

```
Volunteer
  .aggregate(
    {$project: {where:1, shifts:1}}, 
    {$unwind: "$shifts"})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below aggregation query

`$match` to find documents with `volunteers` `email`

`$project` with `$arrayElemAt` to convert the `shift` array to document followed  by `$let` to map the output fields.

```
aggregate({
    $match: {
        "shifts.volunteers.email": "mary@mack.com"
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        where: 1,
        shifts: {
            $let: {
                vars: {
                    doc: {
                        $arrayElemAt: ["$shifts", 0]
                    }
                },
                in: {
                    date: "$$doc.dateNeeded",
                    time: "$$doc.timeslot",
                    details: "$$doc.details"
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

You can also add extra `$project` stage instead of `$let` operator.

```
aggregate({
    $match: {
        "shifts.volunteers.email": "mary@mack.com"
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        where: 1,
        shift: {
            $arrayElemAt: ["$shifts", 0]
        }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        where: 1,
        date: "$shift.dateNeeded",
        time: "$shift.timeslot",
        details: "$shift.details"
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you!!!  Are you aware of any good classes specifically on learning the ins and outs of the aggregation pipeline?  I'm open to learning, and got a few things done myself but this was tough.  Your solution worked perfectly!

Comment: You are welcome. I mostly learn from MongoDB                 
 [aggregation docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) but I believe there are free online classes from [Mongo University](https://university.mongodb.com/courses/schedule). I'm not sure what courses they offer on aggregation framework. You can post at [MongoDB user](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mongodb-user) group to know specifics.